# Run a query in loop, with the results of another query

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

First, I want to list databases with a specific table:

```
 SELECT name
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' 
              THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[TB_INF_CLI]', 'U')
       END IS NOT NULL
```

Then, I want to use the `database_name` inside a loop, to list all indexes of this table ( TB_INF_CLI )  of all these databases, with this query:

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Database_Name
, o.name AS Table_Name
, i.name AS Index_Name
, i.type_desc AS Index_Type
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE i.name IS NOT NULL
AND o.type = 'U'
ORDER BY o.name, i.type
```

How can I do this without `msForEachDb`?

with this solution, I can only list the dabatase i'm connected. I can't understand how can I implement the `database_name` inside this query:

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Database_Name
, o.name AS Table_Name
, i.name AS Index_Name
, i.type_desc AS Index_Type
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE i.name IS NOT NULL
AND o.type = 'U'
and db_name() in
(SELECT name
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' 
              THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[TB_INF_CLI]', 'U')
       END IS NOT NULL 
)
ORDER BY o.name, i.type
```

---

EDIT:

i could achieve what I want with this:

```
create table ##TB_REN (database_name varchar(200),table_name varchar(200),index_name varchar(200),index_type varchar(200))
sp_msforeachdb'use [?]
insert into ##TB_REN( database_name,table_name,index_name,index_type)
SELECT db_name() AS Database_Name
, o.name AS Table_Name
, i.name AS Index_Name
, i.type_desc AS Index_Type
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE i.name IS NOT NULL
and o.name =''TB_INF_CLI''
AND o.type = ''U''
ORDER BY o.name, i.type'
```

Is there  a better solution??

Comment: Not sure why you avoid sp_MSforeachDB, but to solve your issue, you may need to use dynamic sql for sure (if you stick to pure t-sql solution)

Comment: It's because it gives a lot of "results set". I would like a simple table, just like a select. I'm trying to think something with CTE, but with no success either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you said you do not like sp_msforeachdb because of multiple result sets, you can use a temp table to avoid it. The following code should work for you

```
-- return indexes on a table  [dbo].[TB_INF_CLI] across all dbs
--drop table ##t
create table ##t (dbname varchar(100), tblname varchar(100), idxname varchar(100), idxtype varchar(128));

exec sp_msforeachdb 'use ?; insert into ##t 
SELECT DB_NAME() AS Database_Name
, o.name AS Table_Name
, i.name AS Index_Name
, i.type_desc AS Index_Type
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE i.name IS NOT NULL
AND o.type = ''U''
and o.name = ''TB_INF_CLI''
and sc.name=''dbo''
';
select * from ##t;
```

Edit: 
I did not notice you have already had the similar solution as mine for sp_msforeachdb, so the next one is pure dynamic one

```
declare @sqlcmd varchar(max)='';

; with c as (
SELECT name
FROM   sys.databases
WHERE  CASE
         WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE' 
              THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].[TB_INF_CLI]', 'U')
       END IS NOT NULL 
)
select @sqlcmd += 'union all
SELECT ''' + name + ''' AS Database_Name
, o.name AS Table_Name
, i.name AS Index_Name
, i.type_desc AS Index_Type
FROM ' + quotename(name, '[]') + '.sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN ' + quotename(name, '[]')+'.sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN ' + quotename(name, '[]')+'.sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id = sc.schema_id
WHERE i.name IS NOT NULL
AND o.type = ''U''
and o.name = ''TB_INF_CLI''
and sc.name=''dbo''
'
from c
-- remove 'union all' in the 1st line
set @sqlcmd = substring(@sqlcmd, len('union all')+1, len(@sqlcmd));

exec (@sqlcmd);
```

Comment: AFAIK, sp_msforeachdb has bug when dealing with db names that have weird characters inside

Comment: when you say "weird", you mean numbers and [~) etc?

Comment: yes, that is more so for non-English languages.

Comment: @jyao; fwiw, an option for eliminating the last `set` (to remove the leading `union all`) is to change `select @sqlcmd +='union all` with something like `select @sqlcmd += case when @sqlcmd = '' then '' else 'union all' end +'`

Comment: I like your suggestion @markp, and will use it in my future code, thx !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to assemble the statement at runtime, you're locked into Dynamic SQL as far as I know.  I don't like sp_MSforeachdb as well because it's undocumented and I've ran into bugs with it, so here's an alternative that doesn't require its use:

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @cmd = @cmd + N'
UNION ALL

SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(name),N'''') + N' AS Database_Name
, o.name AS Table_Name
, i.name AS Index_Name
, i.type_desc AS Index_Type
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.schemas sc ON o.schema_id =     sc.schema_id
WHERE i.name IS NOT NULL
AND o.type = ''U'''
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4  -- comment out if you want to include system databses

SELECT @cmd = STUFF(@cmd, 1, 13, N'') + N' ORDER BY 1, 2'

PRINT @cmd

EXEC sp_executesql @cmd;
```

Comment: I think this is not going to work, because I have a lot of databases, and the strint is truncated in the middle of the code. I could make a create gloobal table, inserting values inside it. But I'm waiting for a better approach.

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli Did you try executing it?  `PRINT` has a limitation of 8000 characters, but [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) does not suffer from this same limitation: `On 64-bit servers, the size of the string is limited to 2 GB, the maximum size of nvarchar(max). `